# Как передать путь к папке из случайным названиям в качестве параметра функции

Tags: php, pdf

Создаю папку

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $folder = array();    
    $folder = mkdir($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/coupon/coupons_".date("m.d.y").'_'.uniqid(),true);
}
```

Вызываю функцию. Функция запускается в цыкле и нужно чтобы все pdf создавались в одной папке

```
printResualt($cupon,$folder);
```

Создаю pdf  в папке из случайным названиям

```
function printResualt($coupon,$folder){
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',15);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->Image("http://i.piccy.info/i9/8e45b8ff19787bca73662ffb5abeb477/1479364324/100953/1090305/cupon.jpg",0.1,0.1,140,70, 'jpg');
    $pdf->Cell(90);
    $pdf->Cell(200,112,$coupon);
    $file = $folder.'/'.$coupon.".pdf"; 
    $pdf->Output( $file, "F" );
}
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вы задаёте $folder как массив? 2. mkdir возвращает результат попытки создания файлов. А потом вы пытаетесь передать его как имя. 3. У вас нет проверки, что папка создалась. Т.е. вызов функции должен быть после проверки if(isset($_POST['submit'])).

Answer (score 0):

Вначале запомните имя

```
$foldername = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/coupon/coupons_".date("m.d.y").'_'.uniqid()
```

Потом создаете
`$folder = mkdir($foldername,true);`

Потом вызываете функцию

```
printResualt($cupon,$foldername );
```